# Why is my database empty during rails testing, when it should have at least one entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I have a rails server that I'm trying to run tests against using RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium on a mac.  I have a command line program that incorporates the library that performs iOS calls and am attempting to call said program during testing.  Problem is, as far as the controller is concerned, the appropriate table in the database is empty, even after a save call.

So the test looks like:

```
let(:device) {FactoryGirl.create(:device)}
before do
  puts Device.count
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium #otherwise, never even asks for the controller
  Capybara.current_session.mode #not sure why this is necessary, but it appears that without this line, the test fails.  Looks like a timing issue.
  device.save #created by the previous let call via FactoryGirl
  puts Device.count #spits out a count of 1, the device object
  @transactions = Transaction.count 
  system(networkTester, serverURL, device.id, device.password)
end
it "should give an expected response" do
  response.status.should eq(200) #response is empty
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  Transaction.count.should be @transactions + 2
end
```

Inside the devices controller, I've added the debugging code:

```
puts params
@device = Device.[matching criteria].first
puts @device
puts Device.count
```

The idea being that I should be able to see the appropriate parameters (I do), and that the device count should be non-zero (it isn't; it's always zero).

I have to use selenium for this; if I leave the driver at rack_test, then the command line function never gets called (ie, that `puts params` line never gets called).  I also have to call `Capybara.current_session.mode #` for the same reason; ie, without that, the controller never seems to get called (I figured that out through `puts`-based debugging).

The test result itself, at this point, looks like:

```
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: include {:focus=>true}
0
1
{"authcheck"=>nil, ....}

0
2013-07-05 17:58:42.788 NetworkTester[893:707] Not Authorized.
```

That first zero is the first `puts Device.count`, the `1` is the result of `puts Device.count` after `device.save` is called.  The `{}` is the params puts from inside the controller, then a blank line for `puts @device`, and `0` for the count of the `Device` table.  As far as I can tell, that means that in the controller, the `Device` table is empty; however, from the testing side, the `Device` table has one entry.  Because there's nothing in the database as far as the controller is concerned, the NetworkTester fails.

If I run the code outside of the testing environment, the output looks more reasonable; ie, the `Device` table has contents, as far as the controller is concerned.

So why would the `Device` table either have no entries or have one entry during testing?  More importantly, how can I get the `Device` table to have contents during the entire course of the test?

This is Rails 3.2.13, RSpec core of 2.13.1, rspec-rails at 2.13.2, capybara 2.0.3, and selenium-webdriver 2.33.0.  I can provide other versions if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure your "matching criteria" are valid? Have you tried just `Device.first`?

Comment: `Device.count` is 0 inside the controller, but 1 in the test.  `Device.first` is an object in the test, but blank in the controller.  That's the crux of the problem, I think.

Comment: Could you share or point to your entire controller and your entire test? Are you sure that the pass through your controller whose output you are showing corresponds to the body of the `it` test you've shown and not some other activity?

Comment: Unless you've configured it otherwise, your database is probably empty because your test is encapsulating all of the SQL statements within a transaction.   Check out this great post on transactional_fixtures and rspec:  http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

Comment: Wedge's comment is the right answer here.  This always drove me crazy and it looks like customizing the buildup and breakdown of tests via the database_cleaner gem is the way to go.

Comment: @Wedge you should make your comment into an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

in spec/spec_helper.rb